# How to merge arrays by index AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Seeking a way to merge arrays by index like so:

```
var a1:Array = ["a", "b", "c"];
var a2:Array = ["1", "2", "3"];

var a3:Array = result: ["a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3]
```

I've tried concat, push, splice... not getting close. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? This is not a code writing service. Please show some research effort.

Comment: @null right again even I didn't "downvoted" the question (this is the first one he posted)...

Answer (score 2):

```
function arrayMerge(arr1:Array, arr2:Array):Array {
    var o:Array = new Array();
    for (var i:int=0; i<Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length); i++) {
        if (i<arr1.length) o.push(arr1[i]);
        if (i<arr2.length) o.push(arr2[i]);
    }
    return o;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@AndyH :
payamsbr is right, but you may work with Vectors or Arrays

**Perhaps tl; dr;** but this is the principle.
If You want to understand something try those possibilities.
If you don't, just copy and paste some shorter code ;)

```
var v1:Vector.<String> = new <String>["a", "b", "c"];
var v2:Vector.<uint> = new <uint>[1, 2, 3]; // why do you use String here and not uint?
// if you want to convert a uint to a String, use myUint.toString();
function convertVectorToArray(v1:Vector.<String>,v2:Vector.<uint>):Array{
    var mergedArray:Array = new Array();
    if (v1.length != v2.length){
        throw(new Error("   ***ERROR : the two Vectors or Arrays have not the same lenfgth!"));
    }else{
        for(var i:uint = 0; i <v1.length ; i++){
            mergedArray.push(v1[i]);
            mergedArray.push(v2[i]);
        }
    }
    return(mergedArray);
}
function mergeVectors(v1:Vector.<String>,v2:Vector.<uint>):Vector.<Object>{
    var mergedVector:Vector.<Object> = new Vector.<Object>();
    if (v1.length != v2.length){
        throw(new Error("   ***ERROR : the two Vectors or Arrays have not the same length!"));
    }
    for(var i:uint = 0; i <v1.length ; i++){
        mergedVector.push(v1[i] as String);
        mergedVector.push(v2[i] as uint);
    }
    return(mergedVector);
}
var mergedArray:Array = (convertVectorToArray(v1,v2));
var mergedVector:Vector.<Object> = (mergeVectors(v1,v2));
function listArray(arr:Array):String{
    var str: String="";
    if ((v1.length*2) != (v1.length + v2.length)){
        throw(new Error("   ***ERROR : the two Vectors or Arrays have not the same length!"));
    }else{
        for (var i:uint = 0; i < arr.length ; i++){
            str+="typeof(arr[" + i + "]) = " + (typeof(arr[i]) as String).toUpperCase() + ", value = " + arr[i] + "\n";
        }
    }
    return str;
}
function listVector(vect:Vector.<Object>):String{
    var str: String = "";
    if ((v1.length*2) != (v1.length + v2.length)){
        throw(new Error("   ***ERROR : the two Vectors or Arrays have not the same length!"));
    }else{
        for (var i:uint = 0; i < vect.length ; i++){
            str+="typeof(vect[" + i + "]) = " + (typeof(vect[i]) as String).toUpperCase() + ", value = " + vect[i] + "\n";
        }
    }
    return str;
}
trace(listArray(mergedArray));
trace(listVector(mergedVector));
```

You may add a sort() method if You need it (you didn't told about it)
**And Always throw an Error if the 2 Arrays or Vectors don't have the same length**!

Throwing an Error is the best way to understand if something goes wrong...
**This will avoid You a lot of time if You need to debug Your code!!!**

As You can see the output is the same, but if the Vector Class is used correctly, this is more efficient than an Array.

Output :

Since there's a Vector Class, I don't understand a lot of people who chose Arrays instead...
Of course Vector. is a nonsense, but I posted it anyway so You can figure You out the Vector Class.

Output is the same :

```
typeof(arr[0]) = STRING, value = a
typeof(arr[1]) = NUMBER, value = 1
typeof(arr[2]) = STRING, value = b
typeof(arr[3]) = NUMBER, value = 2
typeof(arr[4]) = STRING, value = c
typeof(arr[5]) = NUMBER, value = 3

typeof(vect[0]) = STRING, value = a
typeof(vect[1]) = NUMBER, value = 1
typeof(vect[2]) = STRING, value = b
typeof(vect[3]) = NUMBER, value = 2
typeof(vect[4]) = STRING, value = c
typeof(vect[5]) = NUMBER, value = 3
```

I forgot this easiest way if you really want an Array...
Quick done!

```
var ar1:Array = [1,2,3];
var ar2:Array = ["a","b","c"];
function merge(...arrays):Array {
    var result:Array = [];
    for(var i:int=0;i<arrays.length;i++){
        result = result.concat(arrays[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
trace(merge(ar1, ar2));
// outputs : 1,2,3,a,b,c
```

Another possibility :

```
function populateObject(v1:Vector.<String>, v2:Vector.<uint>):Object{
    var obj = new Object();
    if ((v1.length*2) != (v1.length + v2.length)){
        throw(new Error("   ***ERROR : the two Vectors or Arrays have not the same length!"));
    }else{
        for (var i:uint = 0; i < v1.length; i++){
            obj[v2[i]] = v1[i];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
var o:Object = populateObject(v1,v2);

function listObject(someObj:Object):void{
    var myObj:Object = someObj; 
    for (var i:String in someObj){ 
        trace(someObj[i] + ": " + i); 
    } 
}

listObject(o);

output = 
a: 1
b: 2
c: 3
```

I think that You have a lot of possibilities to use here even it's my longer answer ;)

If You try those possibilities and understand them, this will certainty help You to think to find the best way to deal with Your issue.

But You may also copy and paste some shorter code.
I just wanted to show You that there's more than one answer.
If you understand this, You will be able to go further with coding.

Have fun ;)

Sincerely.
Nicolas

Best regards.
Nicolas.

Comment: Since there's a Vector Class, I don't understand a lot of people who chose Arrays instead...
Of course Vector.<Object> is a nonsense, but I posted it anyway so You can figure You out the Vector Class.
Sincerely.
Nicolas

Comment: See the reference here to figure you out why int or uint is marked as a Number :
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3_Flex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f87.html

Comment: This is log because you want to keep 1 , 2,  3 as Numbers and not as Strings.

Comment: I always avoid to use Arrays and Objects...
Vectors are more useful and efficient!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Payam for answer and non-judgement. Here's how I applied your work:

```
var arr1:Array = ["question1", "question2", "question3"];
var arr2:Array = ["answer1", "answer2", "answer3"];
var o:Array = new Array();

for (var i:int=0; i<Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length); i++) {
    if (i<arr1.length) o.push(arr1[i]);
    if (i<arr2.length) o.push(arr2[i]);
    }

    trace(o); //(question1,answer1,question2,answer2,question3,question3)
```